# How can I validate Postman API response contains the String mentioned CSV file

Tags: testing, postman, web-api-testing, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

When running a Postman requests through Collection runner by passing the values contain in a CSV file for the input parameters, how can I validate each response contain the String text mentioned in the expected value column in this CSV file. I also want to write each response to the Actual result column in this CSV file.

[image]

For example after executing the 1st request in the above pic using the Postman collection runner I want to validate the response contains 'Sydney' as a text value and give the result as 'PASS' or 'FAIL' as well as write the actual response to the Actual result column of the above file. This should continue till the last row of the CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the data in the CSV using the `data` dictionary, for example `data.Scenario`.

Checkout [this article](https://blog.postman.com/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/), chapter "Data variables in pre-request and test scripts".

I don't think it is possible to write data back to the CSV file.